# Reuse previous design for new projects

Tags: page-layout, copyright, branding

I have a client that I did branding and design for a particular program within a non-profit organization.

The program is now cancelled by the organization the client was working for.

Now my contact and another staff that headed the project have left the organization and with government funding have been able to relaunch another project serving the same issue and they are wondering if we can resurrect some of the old design elements used for the previous project.

I'm not sure what the legalities are regarding that, wondering if I can get some info if anyone has previous experience.

Answer (score 2):

If it wasn't mentioned in a contract that everything in the files belong to the person you did them for and if the project was cancelled, these files are yours. What's not yours are the logos used, pictures, and specific elements of the branding you used for the layout.

If the program was cancelled and the files were not paid for, you can do what you want with them, as long you don't use exclusive elements (logos, pictures, specific branding) that belong to the original organization.

The designers worked on these files, and the layouts will certainly require extra tweaking and modifications anyway.

If you're speaking of using a logo you did for a project that was cancelled but was still paid for, then no, I would recommend you to not use it. The fact the project was cancelled doesn't give you the right to use the identity you created for someone else unless they give you that permission. But for generic layouts, that's different.

http://apexcreative.net/owns-design-work/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No definitely not the logo. But I guess that includes some infographics that were developed by modifying public domain icons to reflect certain facts?